# Converting CFG to GNF problem

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, normal-forms

I have a big problem with converting GNF example.

This is my CFG

$
S \to AS\mid BS\mid \lambda\\
A \to aC\mid BCA\mid c\\
B \to AB\mid b\mid \lambda\\
C \to S\mid d
$

I simplified the CFG by removing redundant, $\lambda$-production, unit production.

$
S \to AS\mid BS\mid BA\mid CA\mid AB\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\\
A \to BA\mid CA\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid c\\
B \to AB\mid BA\mid CA\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\\
C \to AS\mid BS\mid AB\mid BA\mid CA\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\mid d\\
$

Then I removed left recursion for the first step to convert to GNF.
I made new non-terminals $N_1$ and $N_2$.

$
S \to AS\mid BS\mid BA\mid CA\mid AB\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\\
A \to BA\mid CA\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid c\\
B \to AB\mid CA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\mid ABN_1\mid CAN_1\mid aCN_1\mid aN_1\mid bN_1\mid cN_1\\
N_1 \to AN_1\mid CAN_1\mid A\mid CA\\
C \to AS\mid BS\mid AB\mid BA\mid BCA\mid aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\mid d\mid ASN_2\mid BSN_2\mid ABN_2\mid BAN_2\mid BCAN_2\mid aCN_2\mid aN_2\mid bN_2\mid cN_2\mid dN_2\\
N_2 \to AN_2\mid A\\
$

Then the problem came that I tried to remove front non-termials such as $B \to AB$, I substitude $A$ into $B$ but the result is $B \to BAB\mid CAB$ and so on, so it produces mored front non-termials.
I'm stuck in here for a long time. Can someone give me a hint to solve it?

In addition, I'm not sure but I thought it may need a CNF form so I converted to CNF.

$
S \to AS\mid BS\mid BA\mid CA\mid AB\mid BCA\mid X_aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\\
A \to BA\mid CA\mid YA\mid X_aC\mid a\mid c\\
B \to AB\mid BA\mid CA\mid YA\mid X_aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\\
C \to AS\mid BS\mid AB\mid BA\mid CA\mid YA\mid X_aC\mid a\mid b\mid c\mid d\\
X_a \to a\\
Y \to BC
$

Comment: You have not removed all left recursion, only direct left recursion.

Comment: There is an algorithm to convert a context-free grammar to Greibach normal form. Program it and apply it on your grammar.

Comment: I misunderstood about left recursion. Thank you for pointing me out.